# how to send pdu with data-digest, if I the initiator is "windows ISCSI Initiator"

Tags: iscsi

I want use data-digest with iscsi pdu, I know that the existence and type of digests are negotiated during the LoginPhase. but If I use windows initiator client how to set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it from the iSCSI initiator GUI.  You can do it for the discovery session, or when you connect to the target, or you can add an additional session to an already connected target.  Here's how to do it on connect:

Click "Connect" to connect to a discovered (Inactive) target.  In the window that appears, click "Advanced".  Check off "Data digest" under "CRC / Checksum", then "OK", and "OK" again to make the connection.

The setting is in the same place for session via the "Discovery" tab and the "Discover Portal" button.